# Write operation in distributed cache

Tags: caching, distributed

There are two tables:

```
filetable
- filename
- fileid
- dirid

directory
- dirname
- dirid
```

The following is the system architecture.
M1, M2, M3 are machines running PHP code.
MYSQL is single MySql database.

```
  M1                 M2                    M3
    \                |                     /
     \               |                    /
      ------------  MYSQL   -------------
```

There is distributed cache present on M1, M2 and M3.
Caching has key-values as

```
dirid -> list_of_fileids
```

For each read request, before going to database each PHP program checks if value for a key is present in distributed cache.

For write operation, the program running on machines (Mn) runs the following steps:

Add file C to directory Z

1. invalidate Z from the cache
2. insert file C into filetable
3. read Z.
4. update cache with Z.

There can be many file insert operations to the same directory running at the same time.

Questions:

1. Under what situation the cache will be out of sync?
2. how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

A distributed cache will behave like any other distributed system and they all have similar constraints.

1. Data that is written to one node takes time to replicate across other nodes. Of course the more nodes, the longer it will take to be present everywhere.
2. If the distributed nodes are on the same virtual network and maybe in the same data center, then the time to make it to all nodes won't be that long.
3. Many distributed systems make a compromise around strongly consistent data (the C in CAP [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem]), so they explicitly state data is different on different nodes.

In my opinion the way to fix it is to:

1. Do nothing, the data is meant to be out of sync for a very short period of time (maybe 10ms?).
2. Handle the discrepancy in the UI. YouTube for example would show the data written in the UI immediately (Javascript) and the write request was sent off. It didn't send the write request and block on reads to show the user the change.

Hope that helps.